# How to move wordpress 'admin_bar_menu' to different location in theme

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, admin

[image]

How to move or create a custom 'admin_bar_menu'? Would this be with hooks? Where to place the code etc.  I am a PHP beginner. Thanks. Let me know if need more details and I will update this.

```
<div class="td-header-sp-top-menu">
    <?php
// show the weather if needed
if (td_util::get_option('tds_weather_top_menu') == 'show') {
    $atts['w_location'] = td_util::get_option('tds_weather_location_top_menu');
    $atts['w_units'] = td_util::get_option('tds_weather_units_top_menu');
    // render the weather
    echo td_weather::render_generic($atts, 'td_top_weather_uid', 'top_bar_template');
}

    // show the date and time if needed
if (td_util::get_option('tds_data_top_menu') == 'show') {
    $tds_data_time = td_util::get_option('tds_data_time_format');
    if ($tds_data_time == '') {
        $tds_data_time = 'l, F j, Y';
    }
    // if the js date is enabled hide the default one
    $td_date_visibility = '';
    if (td_util::get_option('tds_data_js') == 'true') {
        $td_date_visibility = 'style="visibility:hidden;"';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="td_data_time">
        <div <?php echo $td_date_visibility ?>>

            <?php echo date_i18n(stripslashes($tds_data_time)); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

   //show login widget
if (td_util::get_option('tds_login_sign_in_widget') == 'show') {
    //test if user is logd in or not
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //get current logd in user data
        global $current_user;

        //<span class="td-sp-ico-logout"></span>
        echo '<ul class="top-header-menu td_ul_logout">
                    <li class="menu-item">' .
                        get_avatar($current_user->ID, 20) . '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($current_user->ID) . '" class="td_user_logd_in">' . $current_user->display_name . '</a>' .
                    '</li>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="' . wp_logout_url(home_url( '/' )) . '"><i class="td-icon-logout"></i>' . __td('Logout', TD_THEME_NAME) . '</a>
                    </li>
             </ul>';
    } else {

        echo '<ul class="top-header-menu td_ul_login"><li class="menu-item"><a class="td-login-modal-js menu-item" href="#login-form" data-effect="mpf-td-login-effect">' . __td('Sign in / Join', TD_THEME_NAME) . '</a><span class="td-sp-ico-login td_sp_login_ico_style"></span></li></ul>';
    }
}//end login window

if (td_util::get_option('tds_top_menu') != 'hide') {
//shows top menu
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'menu_class' => 'top-header-menu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'td_wp_top_menu',
    'container_class' => 'menu-top-container'
));

//if no top menu is set show link to create new menu
function td_wp_top_menu()
{
    echo '<ul class="top-header-menu">';
    echo '<li class="menu-item-first"><a href="' . esc_url(home_url('/')) . 'wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations">Click here - to select or create a menu</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}

}

?>
</div>
```

So the goal is to move that admin menu dropdown inside my theme's top menu.

Comment: I think you can do this in css side for div id #wpadminbar

Comment: My theme created their own topbar, is there a way to get it onto there by copying it to their topmenu php file?

Comment: it will be better if you can give your theme header code. It must be an additional function put on there. So you just need to move that additional function code into somewhere inside your website.

Comment: Ok thanks, I updated it.

Comment: the default wp admin bar has almost same function with get_option('tds_login_sign_in_widget') . I see there is an option to disable it. If you dont want to disable this theme function you can disable wp admin bar by add this code to your theme <code>add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');</code> 

if you just wan to move / hide that dropdown user menu part you can set display:none in your css theme for this id  #wp-admin-bar-my-account

Answer (score 1):

In my latest version of Wordpress (4.7.5) location of the menu is defined by:

```
#wpadminbar .ab-top-secondary {
    float: right;
}
```

which if you change to:

```
#wpadminbar .ab-top-secondary {
    float: left;
}
```

you will get what you need.

You can do it by adding to your `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php` file these lines:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_layout');
function my_custom_layout() {
    echo '<style>
    #wpadminbar .ab-top-secondary {
        float: left;
    }
    </style>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry the image I uploaded kind've makes it look like it's on the top bar. My theme created their own topbar, where I want to put it, so I'm looking for a way to move that menu dropdown block to anywhere on site.

Comment: You have to inspect this menu wrapper in your browser's developer tools to find out what styles are assigned to it, and then overwrite the styles with the method above.